# How to pass textchange value to the controller using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have multiple rows in my view page. In every row there is one text box. 
When the value in one of these text fields changes, I need to pass both the previous cell which is in same row  and the new value to the Controller, how can I do this?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#Quantity").keyup(function () {

    var url = '@Url.Content("~/")' + "Show/Movie";
    var qtity = '#Timing';

    $.getJSON(url, {
      quantity: $(qtity).val()
    }, function (data) {
      $(".TotalPrice").val(data);
    });

  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store current value as `data` of your element:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#Quantity").keyup(function () {
    var url = '@Url.Content("~/")' + "Show/Movie";
    var qtity = $('#Timing');
    quantity={};
    quantity.current=qtity.val();
    quantity.prev = qtity.data('qty') || ""; //get data of the prev state
    qtity.data('qty',qtity.val()); // set data for next change

    $.getJSON(url, quantity , function (data){ $(".TotalPrice").val(data); } );


  });
});
```